# PC protection from cold and moisture. Recommendations

Tags: pc

I need to put a PC in a non-heated and non-cooled sawmill (I have my reasons). I need it to work during working hours. Sawmill is located in a climate zone where winter temps could be as low as -20C and summer temps can be as high as +30C.

How could I protect the hardware from the moisture (condensation and stuff), cold (and hot) temperatures, and sawdust?

Comment: What does the PC need to do? If you can work with something that has very low power draw it can be passively cooled and that also means it can be water tight. You're probably going to need to look at industrial PCs that are meant to work beside factory machinery that could be throwing fluids or dust all over the PC constantly.

Comment: In addition to Romen's good idea, another choice is to have the screen in the main area of the sawmill, but the computer itself in an area that is a bit less dusty.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue would condensation, if any depending on humidity.
The heat and cooling and be solved with a custom water cooling loop.

heatsink
Radiator
Pump
hose
reservoir
hose fittings
anti-freeze  (stuff you put in your car)

The case can be mostly sealed at that point.  You can run the hoses anywhere you want even outside at that point.  Simple case air filters should keep out any sawdust, although if you want to buy a heppa (quality) filter there no reason you can't.

Unless the PC itself will be subject to rain,snow, or etc there shouldn't be much of a problem.

After that building a small cabinet to surround the PC to keep the elements out.
You can get some vent hosing and attach it to the power supply and let the hose hang down so the water can't go up the hose.

Answer (score 0):

water cooling with external radiators comes to mind but... unless it's a magical sawmill with no sawdust I don't see external radiators working for long.

You said as hot as +30°C (86°F)... um yeah don't worry until ambient gets above 50°C (122°F).  CPU's idle at ~45°C and are good to 85°C no problem.

your vague request for *i need a pc...*  suggests that you do not need a 205w multi-core cpu nor a 200+ watt graphics card.  Therefore, look at home-theater style pc setups and motherboards, which will be mini-itx or micro-itx and often fanless.  Find a suitable pc case that has simple mesh air filters on it.  Locate it in a suitable location and arrange whatever to block sawdust.  I'll bet my nephews bedroom is dirtier than your sawmill and his generic $50 cased pc does not have a problem.  I don't think you require anything special, just a case without a lot of venting, or get a $40 case and manually seal up the extra vent perforations in it.